# Netbeans why does some text appear bold in roboticket?

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, ide, themes

i downloaded the xml file for roboticket from http://www.eclipsecolorthemes.org/, then i went to the http://svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder/ imported this xml file and saved it as a zip. then i imported this zip file in my eclipse. But some text appears to be lighter than usual (like function calls). so it is the same theme but why different appearances in different IDEs? I even checked in preferences  fonts and colors tab -> syntax tab -> in language list java, went off each item and made sure it doesn't have anything bold in it
[image]

Comment: Since there nothing you found set to bold. I think it's  a different font with a wider face and looks bolded compared to the thin font surrounding it.

Comment: @Joraid that thought crossed my mind but all fonts are Courier New

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a bug but a quick workaround would be turning everything that appears light to bold. Now it looks much more like eclipse and of even thickness. **Still unsure whether those semicolons are bold or not** [image]